# What is GitLab project limit on free account?

Tags: gitlab

I just signed in to GitLab, created two private repos and when I try to create one more then I get:

[image]

```
The form contains the following error:
PG::QueryCanceled: ERROR: canceling statement due to statement timeout CONTEXT: while rechecking updated tuple (1,86) in relation "site_statistics" : UPDATE "site_statistics" SET "repositories_count" = "repositories_count"+1
```

Is there a project limit on free account?

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit on the number of private repos ([as stated here](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/04/08/gitlab-dot-com-storage-limit-raised-to-10gb-per-repo/))

But [GitLab recently moved from Azure to Google Cloud Platform](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/06/25/moving-to-gcp/), and this message could be a side-effect.
It was seen before only in [issue 30582](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/30582) and was related to a filesystem problem.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but it's about 200MB per repo for free account,
and about 10GB for payed account